# Using JQuery To Switch Between Icon Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, icons, show-hide

I am trying to use a bit of JQuery / Javascript to switch between Icons I am using for table sorting. I can hide all i elements but am having a bit of trouble specifically targeting the class to hide/show.

**For example these are my table headings in HTML**

```
  <th>Order No &nbsp; <i id='col1' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
  <th>Cust Name &nbsp; <i id='col2' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
  <th>Cust ID &nbsp; <i id='col3' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
  <th>Doc Date &nbsp; <i id='col4' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
  <th>Upload Date &nbsp; <i id='col5' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
  <th>Path</th>
```

What I would like to do specifically is target the element id e.g col1 etc. And then ONLY switch the class name on click between these 3 classes depending on which class is showing at the time.

This is a typical example :

```
<th>Order No <i id='col1' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
```

I will typically be switching between the following three classes.

- fa fa-sort
- fa fa-sort-asc
- fa fa-sort-desc

**SCRIPT**
Any tutorials I have found seem to only target the element id. I have tried something like this but It doesn't work. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#col1").click(function(){
            $(".fa fa-sort").hide();
            $(".fa fa-sort-asc").show();
        });

        $("#col2").click(function(){
           $(".fa fa-sort-asc").hide();
           $(".fa fa-sort-desc").show();
        });

        $("#col3").click(function(){
            $(".fa fa-sort-desc").hide();
            $(".fa fa-sort").show();
        });

    });
```

After seeing G's suggestion I did make the code change however it does not appear to be working. I will add the test page code, please excuse any formatting bugs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

table
{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;margin-top: 20px;

    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;

    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0; 
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.table
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}


th
{
    padding: 10px;color: #fff; 
    background-color: #003466; 
}

#col1, #col2, #col3, #col4, #col5
{
    cursor:pointer;
}


tr
{
    padding: 10px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #efefef;
}
td
{
    padding: 10px; text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script>
$("#col1").click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort').addClass('fa-sort-asc');
     return;
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort-asc')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-asc').addClass('fa-sort-desc');
     return;
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort-desc')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-desc').addClass('fa-sort');
     return;
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order No &nbsp; <i id='col1' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
            <th>Cust Name &nbsp; <i id='col2' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
            <th>Cust ID &nbsp; <i id='col3' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
            <th>Doc Date &nbsp; <i id='col4' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
            <th>Upload Date &nbsp; <i id='col5' class='fa fa-sort'></i></th>
            <th>Path</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly then you want to attach a class onto your col1-3 depending on the class aready attached. You could use the .class() from jQuery to find the elements with a certain class and then .addClass() or removeClass() your classes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. You were correct, that is exactly what I was hoping to achieve. However when I pasted in the script the code still was not firing for me. I have just had another update perhaps this was you also. I have amended the thread to show the entire page. 

I ran a test to simply hide the i elements to check everything was fine and that I hadn't made an error and it worked fine.

Comment: @galeaspablo gave you the right code. He also mentions to write a seperate function. This would be the best and cleanest solution. You could just pass your current class and get the next class returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [galeaspablo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566958/662368)'s answer:

```js
$(".fa").click(function() {

  var $current = $(this);
  var sortDefault = 'fa-sort';
  var sortAsc = 'fa-sort-asc';
  var sortDesc = 'fa-sort-desc';

  var isSortDefault = $current.hasClass(sortDefault);
  var isSortAsc = $current.hasClass(sortAsc);

  $current
    .toggleClass(sortDefault, !isSortDefault && !isSortAsc)
    .toggleClass(sortAsc, isSortDefault && !isSortAsc)
    .toggleClass(sortDesc, isSortAsc);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fa {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
.fa.fa-sort:after {
  content: 'sort_by_alpha';
}
.fa.fa-sort-asc:after {
  content: 'arrow_drop_down';
}
.fa.fa-sort-desc:after {
  content: 'arrow_drop_up';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Order No <i id='col1' class='fa fa-sort'></i>
Cust Name &nbsp; <i id='col2' class='fa fa-sort'></i>
Cust ID &nbsp; <i id='col3' class='fa fa-sort'></i>
Doc Date &nbsp; <i id='col4' class='fa fa-sort'></i>
Upload Date &nbsp; <i id='col5' class='fa fa-sort'></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just switch to the next class, depending on the last class. Note that without the "return", the three ifs would be true.

```
$("#col1").click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort').addClass('fa-sort-asc');
     return;
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort-asc')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-asc').addClass('fa-sort-desc');
     return;
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-sort-desc')){
   $(this).removeClass('fa-sort-desc').addClass('fa-sort');
     return;
  }
});
```

You should create a function if you're ever going to have switch between a lot of classes (I'd do this for 5 or more). But in your particular case, this works just fine.